# Populating an array with 100 integers in C

Tags: c, arrays, cs50

I am taking the free CS50 online class. In one of the video tutorials, the teacher mentions the ability to fill an array with 100 integers, and that it is good practice. I am trying to do that exact thing right now and I am having a difficult time figuring it out.

Note: I have only seen answers including scanf functions and pointers. Is that the only way to solve it, or can it be solved without scanf and pointer?

This is barely the closest I can get...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

int fill_array[100];

for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    fill_array[99] = i;
    printf("%i", fill_array[i]);
}
}
```

Prints out a ton of random numbers and this error:

```
fillingarray.c:14:18: runtime error: index 100 out of bounds for type 'int [100]'
665999424
```

Comment: `i <= 100` --> `i < 100`

Comment: Ah, the off-by-one error strikes again!

Comment: best way `i < sizeof(fill_array)/sizeof(fill_array[0])`

Comment: you need `return 0;`

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate. It also contains an error in `fill_array[99] = i;` which should be `fill_array[i] = i;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

there is one more error in your for loop, To fill the array you should :

```
fill_array[i] = i;
```

The code should look like

```
int fill_array[100];

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
fill_array[i] = i;
printf("%i", fill_array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Got it. Okay... Now... How do I fill it with characters? I have 

`int main(void)
{

char i;
char array[26];

for(i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = i;
        printf("%c \n", array[i]);
    }
}`

Gives me error:
`fillingarray.c:16:14: error: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Werror,-Wchar-subscripts]
        array[i] = i;
             ^~
fillingarray.c:17:30: error: array subscript is of type 'char' [-Werror,-Wchar-subscripts]
        printf("%c \n", array[i]);
`
It's telling me literally what it is... (idk how to make my code appear as yours)

Comment: The easiest way right now is      char array[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't','u', 'v', 'w', 'x','y', 'z' } ;

Answer (score 1):

An

```
int fill_array[100];
```

has indexed 0-99.
Stop the for loop in time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

Also you probably want to fill different indexes than always 99.